# How to place QGraphicsSimpleTextItem in the middle of a QGraphicsLineItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I have inherited the QGraphicsLineItem to a new class called waypointline.
When I construct each way point line I want to put some text in the middle of the line:

```
// Draw line
setLine(localPoint1.X(), localPoint1.Y(), localPoint2.X(), localPoint2.Y());

//Set parent item for text, so it could be properlly deleted later
text.setParentItem(this);
text.setPos((localPoint1.X()+localPoint2.X())/2,(localPoint1.Y()+localPoint2.Y())/2);
text.setText("something");
```

However, the text doesn't appear in the middle of the line at all...
How can I fix this?

Comment: Where do you see the text, relative to the line?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you set the text as a child of the line, its coordinates must be relative to it. So you would do something like

```
text.setPos((width())/2,0);
```